# Importing react-native package when running Vite

Tags: react-native, vite, vitest

I am new to Vite and Vitest. I am experimenting a little bit, trying to add Vitest to a React-native app. I know Vite doesn't really support React Native but I would like to trying running just the tests with Vitest.
I get an error when trying to import React-native modules:

```
Module .../node_modules/react-native/index.js:14 seems to be an ES Module but shipped in a CommonJS package. You might want to create an issue to the package "react-native" asking them to ship the file in .mjs extension or add "type": "module" in their package.json.

As a temporary workaround you can try to inline the package by updating your config:

// vitest.config.js
export default {
  test: {
    deps: {
      inline: [
        "react-native"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When adding the suggested config the tests break inside React-native instead, as if the modules in fact is not supported.
What is going on here? Is React-Native only published as commonjs modules, while only esm-modules is supported by Vite? Is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance,

M.

Comment: It is not supported. https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1321#issuecomment-1129800481

I would just stick with jest for react-native. React-native support is first citizen in jest.

Comment: That's sad. Vitest is even btter than Jest.

Answer (score 0):

Use react-native-web
Only change vite.config.ts like this

```
alias: {
  "react-native": "react-native-web",
},
```